# Broadcast event is not working when HTML is compiled on the fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting to use Angular on a project that needs to be refactored, but I cannot start from scratch, so for now I need to insert some html, with Angular attributes, that need to be compiled on the fly, like this:

```
var html = "<div ng-controller='MyController'><p ng-click="raiseEvent()">Click Me</p></div>";
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'MyProject']);
$injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    $('body').append($compile(html)($rootScope));
});
```

I have two controllers, like the following:

```
function MyController($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.raiseEvent = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    }

};

function MyOtherController($scope) {

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function (event, data) {
        // Code goes here
    });

};
```

My intention is when I click "Clik Me" to broadcast a message for MyOtherController. raiseEvent is called when I press "Click Me" but the listener in MyOtherController is not catching that event. Fuhermore, if I use that HTML on an HTML file I don't get this error, which makes me believe that the problem is with the $compile method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you use MyOtherController?

Comment: MyOtherController is used normally, like:
<section ng-controller="MyOtherController"></section>

Comment: Could you please also add code where you init MyOtherController

Comment: I have just edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the `MyOtherController` on the view.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyController($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.raiseEvent = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    }
}

function MyOtherController($scope) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function (event, data) {
        alert("I've called!");
    });
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <p ng-click="raiseEvent()">Click Me</p>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyOtherController">

</div>
```

This should work.

I've created [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7510/) for you.

Also I suggest you to ivestigate about angular events here: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: I'm using MyOtherController, like you say in your answer. Please check my comment

Comment: @JoaoAlmeida Could your provide code, where you using this controller on the view? Or it will be better if you create the JSFiddle with your code.